# Unknown failure: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for java.lang.String

Tags: android, unsatisfiedlinkerror, android-5.1.1-lollipop

Trying to run my app I get this error:

```
Launching 'app' on LANIX Ilium LT500.
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed.
Installation failed due to: ''pm install-create -r -t -S 3993880' returns error 'Unknown failure: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for java.lang.String android.os.SystemProperties.native_get(java.lang.String, java.lang.String) (tried Java_android_os_SystemProperties_native_1get and Java_android_os_SystemProperties_native_1get__Ljava_lang_String_2Ljava_lang_String_2)
at android.os.SystemProperties.native_get(Native Method)
at android.os.SystemProperties.get(SystemProperties.java:64)
at android.os.Environment.<clinit>(Environment.java:80)
at android.os.Environment.getLegacyExternalStorageDirectory(Environment.java:461)
at android.os.Debug.<clinit>(Debug.java:96)
at android.ddm.DdmHandleHello.handleHELO(DdmHandleHello.java:164)
at android.ddm.DdmHandleHello.handleChunk(DdmHandleHello.java:91)
at org.apache.harmony.dalvik.ddmc.DdmServer.dispatch(DdmServer.java:171)
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: android.os.Debug
at android.ddm.DdmHandleHello.handleFEAT(DdmHandleHello.java:176)
at android.ddm.DdmHandleHello.handleChunk(DdmHandleHello.java:93)
at org.apache.harmony.dalvik.ddmc.DdmServer.dispatch(DdmServer.java:171)
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: android.os.Debug
at android.ddm.DdmHandleProfiling.handleMPRQ(DdmHandleProfiling.java:187)
at android.ddm.DdmHandleProfiling.handleChunk(DdmHandleProfiling.java:88)
at org.apache.harmony.dalvik.ddmc.DdmServer.dispatch(DdmServer.java:171)''
```

It's an LANIX Ilium LT500 phone with Android 5.1 (API level 22). My app's min SDK level is 19.

I'm on Android Studio 3.5.2. There is an old [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43000901) with a similar problem, but none of the answer provide a solution.

I've never had this problem with other phones.
Is this a bug in the phone? Is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: Have you tried the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42595262/8631006

Comment: There is no 'Instant Run' anymore. It was replaced by 'Apply Changes', which is not available for Android 5.1.